# If an adult wizard didn't use their magic at all, would it harm them somehow?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory

Like, if they decided to live a Muggle life and never use their magical abilities, would it affect their lives in a negative way? Would all their magic somehow accumulate and eventually cause some harm to them if they never let it out? We're talking about adult wizards able to control their magic.

Comment: Since you said "We're talking about adult wizards able to control their magic", I edited your title to clarify this. (You also don't have to say "wizard/witch" since wizard is a gender-neutral term in HP.)

Comment: Why would it affect them? had anything you've read suggested that?

Comment: @Edlothiad well, children who repress their magic become Obscuri, so it's not crazy to assume something might happen to an adult.

Comment: McGonagall's mother never used magic when she married a muggle, if memory serves.

Comment: That's why I'm asking, because I'm wondering-would it?  A suppressed magic can harm a child wizard turning him into an Obscurus, but what about adult wizards? Would suppressing their magic somehow harm them too?

Comment: Something akin to "Priest's Disease", AKA [prostatic congestion,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostatic_congestion) perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Doesn't look like it.

Voldemort's mother stopped using magic:

> "Ah," said Dumbledore, "perhaps she could. But it's my belief - I am guessing again, but I am sure I am right - that when her husband abandoned her, Merope stopped using magic...
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 13</sub>

And we see that she dies soon after, but this doesn't appear to be a result of her not using magic - it's because of a broken heart:

> "Your mother had a choice too," said Dumbledore gently. "Yes, Merope Riddle chose death in spite of a son who needed her, but do not judge her too harshly, Harry. She was greatly weakened by long suffering and she never had your mother's courage. And now, if you will stand..."
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 13</sub>

Comment: Oh, I confused McGonagall's mother with Merope

Comment: @Gallifreyan - [You're not too far off.](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-mcgonagall)

Answer (score 2):

In "Short Stories from Howarts of Heroism, Hardship and Dangerous Hobbies" by J.K. Rowling, we learn that McGonagall's mother stopped using her magic whilst married to a muggle:

> She (McGonagall) sensed ,too, how much of a strain it was for her mother to fit in with the all-Muggle village, and how much she missed being with her own kind and of exercising her considerable talents."

This on it's own doesn't necessarily mean that she didn't practice magic at all however when combined with a passage later in which we are told that:

> Minerva had witnessed at close quarters the kind of marriage she might have if she wed Dougal. It would be the end of all her ambitions; it would mean a wand locked away

we can assume that McGonagall's mother refused to practice magic whilst she was married.

Given this, it is clear that adult wizards and witches can choose not to use magic if they are inclined to do so without suffering any real harm.